# RoR, Rspec test mysteriously failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm writing integration tests for creating a user account.

```
describe "with valid information" do
  before (:each) do
    fill_in 'first name',             :with => 'test'
    fill_in 'last name',              :with => 'user'
    fill_in "email",                  :with => "test@shakeshack.com"
    fill_in "password",               :with => "1234567"
    fill_in "password confirmation",  :with => "1234567"
  end

  it "should create a user" do
    expect {click_button "Create"}.to change(User, :count).by(1)

  end
end
```

when I run a local server and fill in the above fields with the same information, the user account is created successfully. The error I am getting is as follows:

```
User pages signup with valid information should create a user
 Failure/Error: expect {click_button "Create"}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
   count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

thanks in advance for solutions or suggestions!!

Comment: does capybara implement a wait in the expect matcher?  Otherwise it might be a race condition where the count hasn't updated yet when the count finishes...

Comment: Even more obvious question, do you actually have it going to a page first? Your example doesn't show it loading a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of suggestions and things to look for:

- Are you sure the User was created successfully when you tested in the browser? Did you verify in the Rails console or some other way?
- Are you sure this is enough data to successfully create a user?
- What usually happens to me in a case like this is a silent failure somewhere, perhaps as the result of not using the bang methods (e.g. `save!`) or not properly checking the return value of the non-bang methods (e.g. `save`).

You can always use capybara's `save_and_open_page` in the spec to view a rendering of the page in the browser during the test:

```
describe "with valid information" do
  before (:each) do
    fill_in 'first name',             :with => 'test'
    fill_in 'last name',              :with => 'user'
    fill_in "email",                  :with => "test@shakeshack.com"
    fill_in "password",               :with => "1234567"
    fill_in "password confirmation",  :with => "1234567"
    save_and_open_page
  end

  it "should create a user" do
    expect {click_button "Create"}.to change(User, :count).by(1)

  end
end
```

Comment: thanks @joshua ! launchy renders a page with empty text fields, does launchy preserve text input? or does this mean that fill_in is not working?

Comment: `fill_in` looks for fields by name, ID, or label text, so you'll need to have at least one of those correct. http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#fill_in-instance_method

Comment: Hope that worked for you. If so, please consider marking my answer as the accepted one. Thanks!

Comment: You're comment was a great help in troubleshooting, and has helped me with other problems since, so I'll mark it as accepted.Thanks again @joshua! However, for anyone who is wondering, the problem in the end was that imageMagick and RMagick were not installed correctly.